# JMeter: How can I randomize post body data several times?

Tags: function, post, dynamic, jmeter

I have a post body data as:

```html
"My data": [{
            "Data": {
                "var1": 6.66,
                "var2": 8.88
            },
            "var3": 9
        }],
```

Here, if I post these details on POST DATA body, it will call "My Data" just once. I want to make it random as starting from 1 to 10 times so that "My data" is running for several times but randomly. If the random value is 2, then "My data" should run twice.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to generate more blocks like this one:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "var1": 6.66,
    "var2": 8.88
  },
  "var3": 9
}
```

It can be done using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following code:

```
def myData = []

1.upto(2, {
    def entry = [:]
    entry.put('Data', [var1: 6.66, var2: 8.88])
    entry.put('var3', '9')
    myData.add(entry)
})

vars.put('myData', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(myData).toPrettyString())

log.info(vars.get('myData'))
```

The above example will generate 2 blocks:

[image]

If you want 10 - change `2` in the `1.upto(2, {` line to `10`

The generated data can be accessed as `${myData}` where needed.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)